# ASP.NET owin self host blocking requests with 404 from files with ".json" extension. Html, txt, js not blocking. Cors turned off, same behavior

Tags: asp.net, owin, self-hosting

I have self hosting app on ASP.NET Owin, that can show html page with login, password, calls web services and show results from web api. Suddenly I hit to the wall, that any static data .json files responds with 404. It's developed is using PhysicalFileSystem.

Part of appliation bundled with javascript frontend that hosts also inside selfhost. It's only bundle.js and bundle.map for debug. I tried turning off cors. But I can't see any .json file. **If I rename it to .txt I see this file.**

Please recoommend debug method to trace this issue or may be you know such behavior.